# Print a specific cell from a string array

Tags: java, arrays, string

I've created a class that includes people data named "Datiutente" and an object based on that class named "du". Every person has a name and a surname (with the set/get methods).

I want to create a system that can provide the user information on a specific person based on the position which they are stored in the array.

I tried using a variable named `vd` to ask the user which person wanted to visualize based on the position that a person gained in the array (inserted in the for cycle), but when I try to print with `vd` it just prints "Name: null". Same if I change "vd" to "1". It always prints "Null".

(Yes, I tested this when I already inserted some data.)

Here's the full code:

```
package appartamento;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Appartamento {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        InputStreamReader input = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader keyb = new BufferedReader(input);
        boolean attiva = true;
        
        do {
            System.out.println("what do you want to do?");
            System.out.println("1 - check for a person");
            System.out.println("2 - Add person");
            int choice = Integer.parseInt(keyb.readLine());
            Datiutente du[] = new Datiutente[10];
        
            if (choice == 2){
                System.out.println("How many people?");
                int hm = Integer.parseInt(keyb.readLine());
       
                for (int i=0;i<hm;i++){
                    du[i] = new Datiutente();
                    System.out.println("insert name:");
                    du[i].setName(keyb.readLine());
                    System.out.println("insert surname");
                    du[i].setSurname(keyb.readLine());
                }  
            }
        
            if (choice == 1){
                System.out.println("which person are you searching?");
                int vd = Integer.parseInt(keyb.readLine());
                System.out.println("position: " + i);
                System.out.println("Name: "+  du[i]);
                System.out.println("Surname: " + du[i]);
            }
        } while (attiva = true);
    }
}
```

and the class "Datiutente":

```
package appartamento;

public class Datiutente {
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String codfis;
    
    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
    
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
    
    public void setSurname(String surname){
        this.surname = surname;
    }
    
    public String getSurname(){
        return surname;
    }
}
```

Comment: Technical note: tables have cells, elements in arrays instead have positions. (which makes a difference if you're trying to search for an answer here, because `cell` may yield completely different search results). Having said that: can you extend this code a little to make it a [mcve]? Right now your `do` block isn't even closed, so it's very hard to see what you intended to write here.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans well that `do` is connected to a `while` at the end of the program, there's a `boolean variable` that keeps the cycle working until it turns false, but i haven't implemented the false outcome yet.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I've added the full code to be more clear.

Comment: `System.out.println("Name: "+  du[i]);` should be `System.out.println("Name: "+  du[i].getName());` and same for surname.

Comment: @Bohemian I've tried this, but now it says that the variable `i` doesn't exist in the `main class`, also I wanted to print a specific person stored in a specific cell, for example "Bob Red" is stored in the first cell, and "Bob Blue" in the second, so the user decides which one to print, if the user inputs 0 it should print "Bob Red", if the user inputs 1 it should print "Bob Blue", it seems like `i` isn't storing anything as the array prints in any case a `null`

Comment: @GR02 search the code in your question for `du[i]` and you’ll find it. I didn’t notice that you posted uncompilable code: You should be coding `System.out.println("Name: "+  du[vd].getName());`, not `System.out.println("Name: "+  du[vd]);` etc

Comment: Also, on an unrelated note: one guess what `do {...} while (attiva = true)` does. Because `=` is _not_ how you check for equality in the majority of programming languages, including Java ;) But yeah: this code won't run, you're referencing `i` outside of the scope in which it exists, so please first look at your code and fix it to the point where it at least _runs_, and ideally during that you'll also fix your current problem but right now no one can really tell what you're doing wrong that causes _this_ problem, because the code you're showing can't run, because It won't compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In every iteration you define the `Datiutente du[] = new Datiutente[10];`, so du is reset to `{null,...,null}` and the data saved in the previous iteration are replaced;
Try to define the array before the loop statement.

Comment: It worked! Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-create-array-of-objects-in-java/):

You need to insert values on object creation, you can also use [hashmaps](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_hashmap.asp)

hashmap will benefit you more I think.

Code sample to fix your stuff.

```
class GFG {    
    public static void main(String args[]){

    // Declaring an array of student
    Student[] arr;

    // Allocating memory for 2 objects
    // of type student
    arr = new Student[2];

    // Initializing the first element
    // of the array
    arr[0] = new Student(1701289270, "Satyabrata");

    // Initializing the second element
    // of the array
    arr[1] = new Student(1701289219, "Omm Prasad");

    // Displaying the student data
    System.out.println(
        "Student data in student arr 0: ");
    arr[0].display();

    System.out.println(
        "Student data in student arr 1: ");
    arr[1].display();
}
}


class Student {

public int id;
public String name;

// Student class constructor
Student(int id, String name)
{
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}

// display() method to display
// the student data
public void display()
{
    System.out.println("Student id is: " + id + " "
                       + "and Student name is: "
                       + name);
    System.out.println();
}
}
```

Comment: What is OP’s problem and how does your answer solve it?

Comment: The OP was creating an array of objects with NULL values.

Following the code above will define new objects:
```object1 = new object("value1","value2")```
so you can use ```object1.val1``` for example